# Trigger every 500px scroll inside a specific container

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, frontend

I'm trying to replicate this behavior from this website: https://www.wealthsimple.com/en-ca/

Has you can see, I want the same paragraph navigation on a scroll when the paragraphs are fade-in/fade-out on the scroll.

The container of those paragraphs seem to be pinned, at every each xxx pixels of scrolling, they switch class for being shown or not.

Any idea which direction I need to take?

I'm currently using `scrollmagic` to pin my container but I have no idea how to trigger each 500px of user scrolling.

Comment: Use a `.fadeIn()` in `.scroll()`, if using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function (event) {
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if(scroll>500)
        alert("do somethg");
    if(scroll%500==0)
        alert("do somethg every 500 scroll")
});
```